# Allow users select their preferred categories and save them

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a news publishing site that will have a private page where logged in users will be allowed to select their preferred categories and save them. They will only see posts in their chosen categories. They should be able to unchoose categories if they wish to. I can't find any solutions online. Though I can control categories based on users roles but that's not the solution I seek.

**I will like to create a page where logged in users can select multiple categories and save. Anytime the users come to the site, they should only see posts in the selected categories.**

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @cabrerahector To create a page where logged in users can select multiple categories and save. Anytime the users come to the site, they should only see posts in the selected categories.

Comment: That's still not a question, Sam. You basically said the same thing. If what you're trying to say is "how do I do all that?", then I'm afraid we can't answer that: your question -as it is at the time of writing- is [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) for Stack Overflow. Please limit your question to a specific problem (eg. *I tried doing X but it doesn't work, why?*) and show us what have you tried so far (as in *code*).